# How to arrive at log(n) running time of loop?

Tags: performance

A loop whose variable is multiplied/divided by a constant factor at each iteration is considered to run in O(log(n)) time.

for example:

```
for(i=1; i<=n;i*2){  
    --some O(1) operations ...  
}
```

How do I calculate or establish that this loop will run log(n) times?

I was previously explained that the factor by which the variable is divided/multiplied will be the base of the log.

I understand running times and their meanings, I just do not understand the math/reasoning that is required to arrive at this particular solution.
How does one mathematically arrive at this solution from knowing that the loop runs from i=1 to i=n multiplying i by 2 each time?

(I am trying to understand this as a basis to understanding how increasing the variable by a constant power leads to a running time of log(log(n)).)

Comment: if the insides of the loop is O(1), then the loop insides are irrelevant. it all comes down to the `i*2` incrementer. since that's doubling every time, it's effectively exponential growth, which means the loop will run the inverse number of times - logarithmic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I make sense of it myself: Try to come up with a function `f(x)` to model your for loop, such that on the x<sup>th</sup> iteration of your for loop, your iterator `i=f(x)`. For the simple case of `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` it is easy to see that for every 1 iteration, i goes up by one, so we can say that f(x)=x, on the x<sup>th</sup> iteration of the loop, i=x. On the 0<sup>th</sup> iteration i=0, on the first i=1, on the second i=2, and so on.

For the other case, `for (i=1;i<n;i*=2)`, we need to come up with an f(x) that will model the fact that for every x<sup>th</sup> iteration, i is doubled. Successive doubling can be expressed as powers of 2, so let `f(x)=2^x`. On the 0<sup>th</sup> iteration, i=1, and 2^0=1. On the first, i=2, and 2^1=2, on the second, i=4, and 2^2=4, then i=8, 2^3=8, then i=16, and 2^4=16. So we can say that `f(x)=2^x` accurately models our loop.

To figure out how many steps the loop takes to complete to reach a certain `n`, solve the equation `f(x)=n`. Using an example of 16, ie `for (i=1;i<16;i*=2)`, it becomes `f(2^x)=16`. log<sub>2</sub>(2^x=16) = x=4, which agrees with the fact that our loop completes in 4 iterations.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Is there any strategic way to figuring out the function if it is not easy to see from the values of x and i? For example, In the case of for(i=2;i<=n;pow(i,2)) I need a function to model that for every xth iteration i is squared. So for iteration 1 i is 2, for iteration 2 i is 4, for iteration 3 i is 16, for iteration 4 i is 256, etc. I don't easily see the function here, is there is any strategy that can be applied to figure it out?

Comment: T(N)=T(2*N)+C, this recurrent formula (from the example above) is wrong and it leads to wrong explanation. because the right one as I've mentioned T(2*N)=T(N)+C or T(N)=T(N/2)+C

Comment: @EvaD In order to understand how to build a recurrent equation, you should look to my explanation, and try to answer on a questions like   1). how much operations it will takes when the input length increases by 1, this will tries to build the right side of T(N+1)=... 2) how much it will takes when the input length doubles, and the answer will build the right side of T(2*N)=... . So, sure this requires some training, but it's not difficult.

Comment: @yvs if my equation is wrong please edit it or just delete it if it's not salvageable

Comment: I'm not going to delete or edit your explanation. but the formula "T(N)=T(2*N)+C" tells us the following: "execution time of the algorithm on input data with length N" equals to "execution time of the algorithm on input data with length 2*N  plus time on some O(1) operations".  Another point is your math formula "log2(2^x=16) = x=4" , i have no comments about it, maybe in some part of the space this is ok.

Comment: @yvs Maybe I am misunderstanding something but I think my comment was misunderstood. I was asking how to obtain a function from given x and y values, but I think thats better suitable on a math page not here. I was just asking given the table of values  x: 1,2,3,4... and y values y:2, 4, 16, 256.... , how to get the function f(x) such that f(x)=y. I don't think it has to do with recurrences because in a sense your recurrence is using 2^x while I was asking how to get the 2^x. (I understand how to get 2^x, didn't understand how to get the function in a different example of a loop).

Comment: @yvs I dont think there is anything wrong with the 2nd formula, log2 (2^x)=x, and log2 (16)=4, so log2 (2^x=16) equals x=4

Comment: @chiliNUT our side of the planet would use notation like : log2(2^x)=log2(16) => x=4.

Comment: and now (unfortunatelly) you've removed everything about algorithm complexity in your answer, but questions was about complexity

Answer (score 1):

According to the wikipedia:

> the time complexity of an algorithm quantifies the amount of time taken by an algorithm to run as a function of the length of the string representing the input.

So lets assume we have a function T from input length N, T(N) means it takes T(N) seconds to run the algo on array of N.

```
for(i=1; i<=n;i*2)
```

In case when we double the array size in your algorithm , we will get a recurrent formula: 
T(2*N)=T(N)+C , this means that if we double the array lenght it takes the same time as T(N) plus a constant time for operation.

There is a theory about how to solve such recurrences, but you can use simple approach with [wolfram alpha solver](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Recurrences.html), so , for this particular case we have the [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(n)%3D%5B%2F%2Fmath:f(n%2F2)%2BC%2F%2F%5D,%20f(1)%3D%5B%2F%2Fdate:B%2F%2F%5D)

When you go in a loop via

```
for(i=1; i<=n;i+=3)
```

then T(N)=T(N-3)+C, which leads us to a linear time of execution.